# Generate adversarial patch on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5, adversarial-attack

When trying to generate adversarial patch on a GPU server I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found
> at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for
> argument tensors in method wrapper_cat)

The code works fine on CPU.

Minimal example:

```
from art.estimators.object_detection.pytorch_yolo import PyTorchYolo
from art.attacks.evasion import AdversarialPatchPyTorch
from inria_utils import load_inria
from evaluation_metrics import evaluate_patch
import torch
from yolov5.utils.loss import ComputeLoss
import yolov5

def load_model():
    class Yolo(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, model):
            super().__init__()
            self.model = model
            self.model.hyp = {'box': 0.05,
                                'obj': 1.0,
                                'cls': 0.5,
                                'anchor_t': 4.0,
                                'cls_pw': 1.0,
                                'obj_pw': 1.0,
                                'fl_gamma': 0.0
                                }
            self.compute_loss = ComputeLoss(self.model.model.model)

        def forward(self, x, targets=None):
            if self.training:
                outputs = self.model.model.model(x)
                loss, loss_items = self.compute_loss(outputs, targets)
                loss_components_dict = {"loss_total": loss}
                return loss_components_dict
            else:
                return self.model(x)

    # Set the device
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
    model = yolov5.load('yolov5s.pt')

        
    model = Yolo(model)
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model.to(device)
    return  PyTorchYolo(model=model,
                        device_type= 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu',
                        input_shape=(3, 640, 640),
                        clip_values=(0, 255), 
                        attack_losses=("loss_total",))

def main():

    detector = load_model()

    x, _ = load_inria(subset="train", num_samples=8)#x is a numpy array
    # I have tried x to tensor and set the device to cuda but ap.generate expects np array
    target = detector.predict(x) #its a list

    ap = AdversarialPatchPyTorch(
        estimator=detector,
        rotation_max=8,
        scale_min=0.4,
        scale_max=1,
        learning_rate=1,
        batch_size=16,
        max_iter=5,
        patch_shape=(3, 200, 200),
        patch_type='square',
        verbose=True,
        optimizer='Adam')
    
    ap.generate(x=x, y=target)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried reducing the problem but I cannot reduce it more than the above example.

Comment: Post full stacktrace. Which line of code causes the error? What are the inputs to that line of code? Print out the device for each tensor input with `<tensor>.device`. Are they all on the same device?